# React Router props.history

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, react-router, react-navigation-v5

I'm a new to React.js with asp.net core, and I got an error that I don't understand.

I created protected route like that :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import auth from './auth.js'

export const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        <Route 
            {...rest} 
            render = {props => {
                if(auth.estAuthentifier()){
                    return <Component {...props}/>
                } else {
                    return <Redirect to={
                        {
                            pathname: "/",
                            state: {
                                from: props.location
                            }
                        }     
                    } />
                }

            }}
        />
    );
}
```

In my App.js, I added the protected route like that :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router';
import { Login } from './components/Login'
import { Layout } from './components/Layout';
import { Home } from './components/Home';
import { ProtectedRoute } from './components/protected.route';

export default class App extends Component {
  static displayName = App.name;

  render () {
    return (
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
            <Layout>
              <ProtectedRoute exact path="/home" component={Home}/>
            </Layout> 
            <Route path="*" component={() => "404 NOT FOUND"}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And, the Layout component render all components with my NavBar included :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container } from 'reactstrap';
import { NavMenu } from './NavMenu';

import '../css/Layout.css';

export class Layout extends Component {
  static displayName = Layout.name;

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="conteneur-principal">
        <NavMenu />
        <Container>
          {this.props.children}
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is the next : I put the logout button in my navigation bar component but when I'm trying to logout and redirect to Login, i got the following error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

NavMenu.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'reactstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import auth from './auth';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import '../css/SideBarNav.css';

export class NavMenu extends Component {
  static displayName = NavMenu.name;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    console.log(this.props);

    this.deconnexion = this.deconnexion.bind(this);

  }

  deconnexion = () => {  

    auth.logout(() => {
      this.props.history.push('/');     //LINE IN ERROR
    })

  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="conteneur-menu">
        <img src="images/familieu-logo-clear.png" alt="logo-familieu" title="logo-familieu" className="is-clickable logo-familieu"/>
        <div className="conteneur-link"> 
          <NavLink tag={Link} className="menu-link" to="/">Home</NavLink>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Déconnexion" className="btn-deconnexion" onClick={this.deconnexion}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What should I do to make my logout button work ?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NavMenu.js you are importing the `withRouter`, but is not used.

Wrap the export of component with `withRouter` like this:

```
export default withRouter(NavMenu);
```